# Simple Method to Reload Model Plugins?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a simple method to reload model plugins in Gazebo when they are recompiled?
I see PluginT<...>::Create() and ModelPlugin::Create() using dlfcn.h / ltdl.h, and was wondering if there currently is a technique to easily reload model plugins if the model is destroyed and a new one is created.

Reposted from [here](http://forum.theroboticschallenge.org/index.php?topic=63.0).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/496/simple-method-to-reload-model-plugins?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There currently is not a mechanism to do this.

I have created a feature request:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/299/reload-plugins-via-gui

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrisfort](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7997/chrisfort/) on 2019-01-16**:
Is there a command line option to reload sensor plugins?